# FasterCSV: Read Remote CSV Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, csv, fastercsv

I can't seem to get this to work.  I want to pull a CSV file from a different webserver to read in my application.  This is how I'd like to call it:

```
url = 'http://www.testing.com/test.csv'
records = FasterCSV.read(url, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol)
```

But that doesn't work.  I tried Googling, and all I came up with was this excerpt: [Practical Ruby Gems](http://books.google.com/books?id=QC0rgGTmeNAC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=fastercsv+%22open+url%22&source=web&ots=aMLo1W-6Er&sig=-DmI4m_AeHGL3ulqRgKNFKbEEHU&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=1&ct=result)

So, I tried modifying it as follows:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = 'http://www.testing.com/test.csv'
csv_url = open(url)
records = FasterCSV.read(csv_url, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol)
```

... and I get a `can't convert Tempfile into String` error (coming from the FasterCSV gem).

Can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'open-uri'
url = 'http://www.testing.com/test.csv'
open(url) do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    FasterCSV.parse(line) do |row|
      # Your code here
    end
  end
end
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/OpenURI.html
http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

I would retrieve the file with `Net::HTTP` for example and feed that to `FasterCSV`

Extracted from `ri Net::HTTP`

```
 require 'net/http'
 require 'uri'

 url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/index.html')
 res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
   http.get('/index.html')
 }
 puts res.body
```

Comment: I tried that and now I'm getting an error: File name too long.  After which, it lists the entire contents of my CSV file.  I'm looking at the documentation now; Any suggestions?

Comment: "res.body" will be a String which you should probably split into an Array on "\n" and feed that to `FasterCSV.read`

Comment: open-uri is higher level than Net::HTTP, I think it is better suited for neezer's example.

Answer (score 1):

You just had a small typo. You should have used `FasterCSV.parse` instead of `FasterCSV.read`:

```
data = open('http://www.testing.com/test.csv')
records = FasterCSV.parse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would download it with rio - as easy as:

```
require 'rio'
require 'fastercsv'

array_of_arrays = FasterCSV.parse(rio('http://www.example.com/index.html').read)
```

Answer (score 0):

I upload CSV file with Paperclip and save it to Cloudfiles and then start file processing with Delayed_job.

This worked for me:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = 'http://www.testing.com/test.csv'
open(url) do |file|
  FasterCSV.parse(file.read) do |row|
    # Your code here
  end
end
```