# FasterCSV: columns into an array -- rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, csv, import, fastercsv

I'm trying to get fastercsv setup so that rather than parsing each row, it will place each column into an multi array.

```
CSV import file:
id, first name, last name, age
1, joe, smith, 11
2, jane, doe, 14

Save to array named people:
people[0][0] would equal id
people[2][1] would equal jane
```

This is what I currently have:

```
url = 'http://url.com/file.csv'
open(url) do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    FasterCSV.parse(line) do |row|
      row
    end
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why a multi-dimensional array? What is wrong with an array of hashes which is much nicer to read.

Comment: I wanted a multi-dimensional array setup for each column because I don't need to store the data in active-record nor do I know what the column names will be, I want to take the array and build a xml file out of it so that each column name will be each column's attribute... if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks EmFi, with your help I was able to come up with a solution.

This takes a remote url csv file and loads it into a multi-dimensional array, based on columns.

```
require 'rio'
require 'fastercsv'

url = 'http://remoteurl.com/file.csv'
people = FasterCSV.parse(rio(url).read)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the [FasterCSV documentation?](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/)

If you did, you would know that the easiest way to do what you want is:

```
people = FasterCSV.read('http://url.com/file.csv')
```

Comment: Also tried to read a local file and I got a compile error:
"odd number list for Hash"

Comment: Odd number list for hash should have nothing to do with FasterCSV. Any chance you're using braces to bookend your if blocks?

Comment: Also you've got to go through some tricks to read from a URL, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435634/fastercsv-read-remote-csv-files

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CsvMapper](http://github.com/pillowfactory/csv-mapper) on top of FasterCSV
It s a life saver